# Fix this Entity Framework migration, 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema, in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, authentication, blazor

I'm starting with the default Blazor app in Visual Studio 16.3.7 with authentication:

[image: Visual Studio project]

I go to the registration page, enter the email and password, and click the Register button and up comes the following error:

[image: Blazor error message]

Next I go to Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, and run ***Update-Database***, getting the following error:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\Halaspnet-BlazorAuthentication-0X0X0X0X0X0-X0X0-X0X0-X0X0-0X0X0X0X0X0.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

The message points to the culprit, a backslash is missing from the file specification. It should be **C:\Users\Hal\aspnet...** , not **C:\Users\Halaspnet...**

So, how do I fix this? I can't find the string "CREATE DATABASE" anywhere in my solution.

Also, how do I get this to Microsoft as a bug report?

Comment: This is not a Blazor problem. The filenames are the domain of SQL server, you (still) have a problem with the configuration there. Maybe re-install SQLExpress.

Comment: Normally the .mdf files are created in your c:\users\{user name}\ folder.  Not sure why it's trying to create in c:\users\ where you're getting a permission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I created the database that the 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs wanted using Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer. Then I ran Update-Database in the Package Manager Console, and it completed successfully.

The problem seems to be that I was using the Express edition of SQL Server.

This link got me to the fix for this problem:
[Creating A Step-By-Step End-To-End Database Server-Side Blazor Application](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4318/Creating-A-Step-By-Step-End-To-End-Database-Server-Side-Blazor-Application.aspx)

Comment: Link has changed to: https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/34